# Expiration and Reminder custom message

Tags: docusignapi

Is EmailNotification in Recipient set custom message for reminder and expiration mails?

Is possible to set custom message for reminder and expiration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are in fact the 2 emails that you cannot customize. DocuSign will pre-pend REMINDER and EXPIRATION PENDING to the subject of the original email.